# Get-Content issue with -eq as string

Tags: powershell

As part of a bigger script I need to verify a file contents before continuing. However, it's not working when I use `| Out-String`.

Note this needs to work under powershell v2 unfortunately. The file I am looking at contains the data:

```json
{"somedata":5,"hello":[]}
```

If I remove `| Out-String` from the command then it tells me the file matches.

But if I add data to the file, then it still tells me the file matches when it doesn't. If I add `| Out-String` then it tells me the file doesn't match when it does...

```
$filecheck = Get-Content ("C:\temp\hello.txt") | Out-String
Write-Host $filecheck
if ($filecheck -eq '{"somedata":5,"hello":[]}') {
    Write-Host "file matches"
} else {
    Write-Host "doesn't match"
}
```

Comment: Why do you pipe it into Out-String? Your code works if you remove that.

Comment: because if there are any additional lines in the file then it still evaluates to true when it's not.

Comment: OK, I see. I only tried with one line in the file.

Answer (score 6):

As how to fix the issue, see @tukan's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49647970/503046). Anyway, for learning purposes, let's explore the root cause, namely using the `Out-String` cmdlet. It actually adds a newline to the string. Like so,

```
PS C:\temp> $filecheck = Get-Content ("C:\temp\hello.txt") | Out-String
PS C:\temp> write-host $filecheck
{"somedata":5,"hello":[]}

PS C:\temp>
```

As the data contains a newline, it isn't equal to the string literal used in the if statement. Thus the comparison fails. Remove the `Out-String` and it works:

```
PS C:\temp>$filecheck = Get-Content ("C:\temp\hello.txt")
PS C:\temp> $filecheck
{"somedata":5,"hello":[]}
PS C:\temp> $filecheck -eq '{"somedata":5,"hello":[]}'
True
PS C:\temp>
```

Earlier you noted that `Out-String` was needed as otherwise adding data would still make the comparison to fail. Why is that? Let's say the data in file is

```
{"somedata":5,"hello":[]}
{"moredata":1,"foo":bar}
```

What now happens is that `Get-Content` will give you an array of strings. The 2nd line consists of `{"moredata":1,"foo":bar}` plus a newline. Passing such a construct to the comparison will evaluate just the first element, thus a match.

When you pass an array to `Out-String`, the result is actually a string with data, newline, data and extra newline:

```
PS C:\temp> $filecheck|out-string
{"somedata":5,"hello":[]}
{"moredata":1,"foo":bar}

PS C:\temp>
```

This obviously isn't equal to the string literal used in the if statement.

Comment: Good problem analysis. I'm not sure Tukan's answer is a proper solution to the problem, though, since the OP seems to want to check the entire content of a JSON file. `$filecheck = (Get-Content "C:\temp\hello.txt" | Out-String).Trim()` is probably a better approach.

Comment: yes perfect thank you! the trim will work as I wasn't aware it was adding a new line when using out-string

Answer (score 1):

**Edit** - the script will exit on first match.
**Edit2** - you don't need the `Else` branch if nothing is found print 'failed' at the end suffice.

What about piping into `Foreach-Object` like this:

```
 (Get-Content 'C:\<our_path>\test.txt') |
        Foreach-Object { If ($_ -eq '{"somedata":5,"hello":[]}') {write-host 'matches'; exit}} 
 write-host 'failed'
```

I have kept your format of `-eq`, even thou, I would recommend `regex` for string/text search.

Comment: This gives a line-by-line comparison of the file, not sure if this is what the OP wants?

Comment: @JamesC you are right. Hard to say from the question.

Comment: hi, see what you mean yes this would work but it I only want it to match on the complete file with the first string.

Comment: @Ian you mean exit on first occurrence?  If yes, see my edit.